# Function Pointers - Why does this code crash?

Tags: c, function, pointers, crash, function-pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>  
int main(void)
{
  int (*fp)(void); 
  printf("Loopy.\n");
  fp = &main; //point to main function
  fp(); //call 'main' 

  return 0;
}
```

Instead of infinitely executing the loop, the "loop" executes for around 10-20 seconds on my machine then gets the standard Windows app crash report. Why is this?

Compiler: GCC
IDE: Code::Blocks
OS: Win7 64bit

[image]

Comment: [Working fine to me](http://ideone.com/Qzcc3Q). Can't reproduce.

Comment: Exception code `0xc00000fd` is a stack overflow. What were you expecting?

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst I was expecting an infinite loop, I was experimenting. Also, like the vast majority of people I didn't read the crash details :).

Comment: Gotcha, well you can always expect a stack overflow when you're expanding memory on the stack, but never managing it.

Comment: "like the vast majority of people" should be doing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

10..20 seconds is about as long as it takes your computer to overflow the stack.

A new stack frame is created every time that your function calls itself recursively through a function pointer. Since the call is done indirectly, the compiler does not get a chance to optimize the tail call into a loop, so your program eventually crashes with stack overflow.

If you fix your program to stop looping after a set number of times, say, by setting up a counter, your program would run correctly to completion ([demo](http://ideone.com/q7e1jN)).

```
#include <stdio.h>  

int counter = 200;

int main(void)
{
  int (*fp)(void); 
  printf("Loopy %d\n", counter);
  fp = &main; //point to main function
  if (counter--) {
      fp(); //call 'main' 
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Fantastic answer, had been recently taught about stack frames, I should've seen it! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is **compiler dependent** it may crash after **stack overflow** or just hang there without no response, but the only reason can be pushing too many stack frames in the memory stack